# POP history will clear function in location.state?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

im just not sure what is going on, is this expected behaviour or not.

First of, I what to send function around in state of location

`/path1`

```
  const state = {
    action: () => {},
    other: 'other'
  }
  this.props.history.replaceState(state, '/path2')
```

then i will send the state around to some route
`/path2`

```
  this.props.history.replaceState(this.props.location.state, '/path3')
```

at this point if i log the state of location, `action` still there

```
console.log(this.props.location.state) //  print { action: fn(), other: 'other' }
```

But when I perform `go back` on the browser, right now i am at route `/path1`

```
console.log(this.props.location.state) //  print { other: 'other' }
```

You guys can see that the `function` is removed from location's state.
My question is why this happening? Is there any reason behind this?

Even if I put `function` into Object
For example

```
  const state = {
    action: { moreAction: () => {} },
    other: 'other'
  }
  this.props.history.replaceState(state, '/path2')
```

When perform go back in browser, the location's state still be like

```
console.log(this.props.location.state) //  print { action: {}, other: 'other' }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The contents of location state must be JSON serializable – you cannot put functions in there.

Comment: Yep, I kind of know of my doing was not purpose of the location state, but for some reason, I need to do it for specific case. Actually I can pass function around, but unfortunately when go back, it was cleared out.